# Aren't these overloads ambiguous?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object) 
ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String)
```

Isn't `string` an `Object`?  How do I call the first overload with a string as the third parameter?

Comment: If you pass a `string` as the 3rd parameter it will be interpreted as the controller name. Are you trying to pass a string as a route parameter?

Comment: Yes, that {id} thingy. I wanted to explore not using new { Id=xx } but just having /xx in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to cast your string into object `(object)"my string"`.

I know this is really ugly, but this is the only way. And I agree with you that many method overloads from the HtmlHelper are really ambiguous.